# What is the most efficient way to build up a graph starting with one node?

Tags: python, json, recursion, social-networking

I'd like to know the most efficient way to 'build up' an undirected graph starting from a single node.

Background:

I'm working with an api that returns json objects that look like this (in a very simplified form):

Ex.1

```
{
  'Name': 'John',
  'friends': ['Sally', 'Bob'],
}
```

Ex.2

```
{
  'Name': 'Sally',
  'friends': ['John', 'Bob'],
}
```

Ex.3

```
{
  'Name': 'Bob',
  'friends': ['Sally', 'John'],
}
```

Suppose I want to build an undirected graph of John's 'network' in a dict of lists representation:

```
graph = {'John': ['Sally', 'Bob'],
         'Sally': ['John', 'Bob'],
         'Bob': ['Sally', 'John']
        }
```

I created a `Person` class to make it easier to work with the json objects:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = json.loads(requests.get(url+str(self.name)+url2).text)['results'] #this is basically the api call that gets the json object, url and url2 are just strings

    def friends(self):
        return self.data['friends']
```

which has a `friends()` method to interact with the json object. Calling `Person('John').friends()` makes an api call, gets the json object representing John and returns `['Sally', 'Bob']` i.e. a list of John's friends.

Because of the structure of these json objects, I can keep recursing through the friends list to build up a network graph. My attempt:

```
def build_graph(name, adict, visited):
    visited.append(name) #record that you've visited this person
    adict[name] = Person(name).friends() #THIS IS AN API CALL. Create a dict entry where the key is the person's name and the value is their list of friends
    for friend in adict[name]: #then for every friend of this person
        if friend not in visited: #if I have not visited them
            build_graph(friend, adict, visited) #continue building the graph
    return adict #at the end return the graph
```

To use this to get a graph of John's network you would have to call `build_graph('John',{},[])` i.e. pass it an empty dict and list that it can start from to build up the graph.

The problem is `build_graph` takes ~20 seconds to build up a graph of 200 nodes. I'm not sure if all those api call are the bottleneck or if I've just written the function poorly. How can I speed up `build_graph` ?

Comment: I cannot see serious problem in your code. What is the `Person` class and what does it do ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I edited the question to add the code for the Person class

Comment: IMHO the HTTP requests takes most of the 20 seconds, and not your own code ...